# Complex Context handling

Tags: xslt

I have a bit of a complex requirement. I need to get the values from another node while using the context from another node.
Please see sample below:

```
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>111</epc>
  <epc>222</epc>
 </epcList>
 <material>ABC</material>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>containerFOR111222</epc>
 </epcList>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>333</epc>
 </epcList>
 <material>DEF</material>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>containerFOR333</epc>
 </epcList>
</ObjectEvent>
<AggregationEvent>
 <parentID>containerFOR111222</parentID>
 <childEPCs>
  <epc>111</epc>
  <epc>222</epc>
 </childEPCs>
</AggregationEvent>
<AggregationEvent>
 <parentID>containerFOR333</parentID>
 <childEPCs>
  <epc>333</epc>
 </childEPCs>
</AggregationEvent>
```

The number of parent nodes will depend on the unique materials. so in this case there will be 2. Output should be something like this:

```
<MATERIAL>
 <BATCH>ABC</BATCH>
 <SERIES>
  <TOTAL>2</TOTAL>
  <EPCS>
   <EPC>111</EPC>
   <CONTAINER>containerFOR111222</CONTAINER>
  </EPCS>
  <EPCS>
   <EPC>222</EPC>
   <CONTAINER>containerFOR111222</CONTAINER>
  </EPCS>
 </SERIES>
</MATERIAL>
<MATERIAL>
 <BATCH>DEF</BATCH>
 <SERIES>
  <TOTAL>1</TOTAL>
  <EPCS>
   <EPC>333</EPC>
   <CONTAINER>containerFOR333</CONTAINER>
  </EPCS>
 </SERIES>
</MATERIAL>
```

I already got the MATERIAL, BATCH, SERIES, TOTAL, EPCS and EPC right. The problem is with the CONTAINER field. I cannot get the value of the 2nd context (containerFOR333). I'm just getting the value of the 1st context :(

This is the mapping i have now. I don't have an idea for CONTAINER:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ObjectEvent/material">
 <MATERIAL>
  <BATCH>
   <xsl:value-of select="./material"/>
  </BATCH>
  <SERIES>
   <TOTAL>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(./epcList/epc"/>
   </TOTAL>
    <xsl:for-each select="./epcList/epc">
     <EPCS>
      <EPC>
       <xsl:value-of select="./epcList/epc"/>
      </EPC>
      <CONTAINER>???</CONTAINER>
      </EPCS>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </SERIES>
 </MATERIAL>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My actual source, target message and mapping is much much more complex than this so hopefully ill be able to start with a simple solution then work my way up to the higher complexities

Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to provide the rules of this game. How does one know which ObjectEvent is a "container", and which "non-container" ObjectEvent it belongs to?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The 2nd ObjectEvent is the container for the epcs in the 1st ObjectEvent. The 4th ObjectEvent is the container for the epcs in the 3rd ObjectEvent. So we need to put the containerFOR111222 for epcs 111 and 222 then containerFOR333 for epc 333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If - as you say in the comments - the `ObjectEvent` nodes come in pairs, then you need to do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ObjectEvent[position() mod 2 = 1]">
    <MATERIAL>
        <BATCH>
            <xsl:value-of select="material"/>
        </BATCH>
        <SERIES>
            <TOTAL>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(epcList/epc)"/>
            </TOTAL>
            <xsl:for-each select="epcList/epc">
                <EPCS>
                    <EPC>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </EPC>
                    <CONTAINER>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../following-sibling::ObjectEvent[1]/epcList/epc"/>
                    </CONTAINER>
                </EPCS>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </SERIES>
    </MATERIAL>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

Demo (using a **well-formed** input): http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLj

Comment: thanks michael, there's a lot about the code that I do not know. let me research position(), mod, sibling, ::, so i can apply it in my mapping. ill update you if i got good progress

Comment: Hi Michael,apologies. but what if it's not paired. I mean what if the 1st 2 objectevents have the epc values while the next 2 objectevents have the containers? <ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>111</epc>
  <epc>222</epc>
 </epcList>
 <material>ABC</material>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>333</epc>
 </epcList>
 <material>DEF</material>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>containerFOR111222</epc>
 </epcList>
</ObjectEvent>
<ObjectEvent>
 <epcList>
  <epc>containerFOR333</epc>
 </epcList>
</ObjectEvent>

Comment: @XSLTnewbie If the input is different, then the stylesheet needs to be different too. If that's a real-world scenario, I suggest you post it a separate question.